# Classifcation Time Series Error in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, classification, modis

In the below code I was going to do classification process for time series data but in training data collection returned this error:
[image]

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b81fe0a02ece289b3c788a5ccba67ac9

```
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(table);

var start = '2018-01-01';
var end = '2019-01-01';

var persiannData = function(img){
  return img.clip(table)
  .multiply(255 / 2.0).toInt()
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
};


var persiann25km = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/PERSIANN-CDR")
.filterDate(start, end)
.filterBounds(table).map(persiannData);


print('persiann25km',persiann25km);


/// ancillary data

var dem = ee.Image("USGS/GTOPO30")
.clip(table);


var ndvi = function(img){
  return img.clip(table).addBands(dem)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
};

var evi = function(img){
  return img.clip(table)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
};

var lst = function(img){
  return img.clip(table).select('LST_Day_1km').multiply(0.02)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
};

var modisNDVI = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/MOD09GA_006_NDVI")
.filterDate(start, end)
.filterBounds(table)
.map(ndvi);

var modisEVI = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/MOD09GA_006_EVI")
.filterDate(start, end)
.filterBounds(table)
.map(evi);

var modisLST = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD11A1")
.filterDate(start, end)
.filterBounds(table)
.map(lst);


// data integration

var modisDataset = modisNDVI.combine(modisEVI).combine(modisLST);

print('modisDataset',modisDataset);



var innerJoin = ee.Join.inner();

var filterTimeEq = ee.Filter.equals({
  leftField:'system:time_start' ,
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
});


var innerJoinModis = innerJoin.apply(modisDataset, persiann25km, filterTimeEq);

print('persiann & modis', innerJoinModis);


var datasetMap = ee.ImageCollection(innerJoinModis.map(function(feature){
  
  return ee.Image.cat(feature.get('primary'), feature.get('secondary'));
  
}));


print('datasetMap',datasetMap);

// modelling process


var classificationProcess = datasetMap.map(function(img){
  
  var bandNames = img.select('NDVI','EVI','elevation','LST_Day_1km')
  .bandNames();
  
  var trainingData = img.stratifiedSample({
    numPoints: 100,
    classBand: 'precipitation',
    region: table,
    scale: 1000,
    });
    
  var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(80)
  .train({
    features: trainingData,
    classProperty: 'precipitation',
    inputProperties: bandNames
  });
  
  var classified = img.select('NDVI','EVI','elevation','LST_Day_1km')
  .classify(classifier);
  
  
  return classified
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);

});


print('classificationProcess',classificationProcess);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your inputs don't exist on all days.  (Specifically, there is no LST on day 42 and others).  You can't train a classifier with missing points in your data, so the classifiers for those days fail.

```
print(ee.Image(datasetMap.toList(1, 42).get(0))
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.count(), table.geometry()))
```

That said, Creating a new classifier for each day doesn't sound like a good plan.  You won't have any way to judge their quality.  Some of them will be good and some will be bad (and some wont work at all, like this one).  So you wont know if the classification results on any particular day are due to a good/bad classifier or good/bad training from that day.

Comment: Great. Nevertheless, what is the best plan for classification time series in GEE?

Comment: Build 1 classifier and use it on all days.

Comment: Good Idea. Could you show an example, please? I know how to do classification process but I don't know how can I use one classifier for all days.

Comment: It's unclear what you're really trying to do, since you're doing a classification using precipitation as a categorical class, but you just need to move the training out of the map to produce a classifier you can reuse: https://code.earthengine.google.com/9b79bf4231c57b2f95466407ec1604ce